# All Permutations of a String in Python using Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, permutation

I have this following Python code which returns a list of all the permutations of a given string using recursion. I tried my best to understand the working of the code but I am failed to do so. Can anyone please give me a breakdown of the code mentioned below?

```
def permute(s):
    out = []

    # Base Case
    if len(s) == 1:
        out = [s]

    else:
       # For every letter in string
       for i, let in enumerate(s):
           for perm in permute(s[:i] + s[i+1:]):
                # Add it to output
                out += [let + perm]
    return out

permute('abc')
['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the string is one, there is only on permutation, so it returns only that string in this case.

If there are more letters, however, it goes through every letter in the string, they are each treated as the first letter in the permutations that get added in `out` in that iteration. Then it goes through every permutation of the rest of the string, and adds each of those to `out`, with `let` being the first letter.

But as `permute('aab')` wouldn't yield `['aab', 'aba', 'baa']`; each entry would be in the returned list twice.

To avoid that, use sets instead. So `out = set()`, `out = {s}`, and `out.add(let + perm)` instead of `out = []`, `out = [s]` and `out.append(let + perm)`.